# Echarts : Heatmap tiles cut on edges

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

Echarts version : 4.8

I'm using scatter and heatmap series on the same map.

The problem is that on the right border the heatmap are cut until the last point.

How can I display the full heatmap tiles ? what am I missing here ?

Thanks

[image: example]

[image: example 2]

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to determine the problem from your picture, it would be easier with the configuration code, but I will try.

Try to add to the chart config the grid option. With grid you will can control padding of the visual chart part against outside space.

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid

You need to change left, right, bottom and top options to move the edges.